# How to replace variable with actual value inside the double quotes in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have one variable val = "O'brien" and I want to create a following string using this variable.  -->

```py
s1 = "{\"id1\":\"O'brien\"}"
```

I tried with this:

```py
s1 = "{\"id1\":\"'{}'.format(x)\"}"
```

However, It's giving me literal values as

```py
'{"id1":"\'{}\'.format(x)"}'
```

What I want instead is

```py
s1 = "{\"id1\":\"O'brien\"}"
```

So that, I can make it dictionary using

```py
json.loads(s1)
```

Which will give me this output:

```py
{'id1': "O'brien"}.
```

I tried with many ways but couldn't get it, please suggest some good ways

Comment: You have to call `format` on the string object, not put it inside the string.

Comment: `s1='{{"id1":"\'{}\'}}'; s1.format(val)` IIUC

Comment: The most reasonable way to do this is `s1 = json.dumpa(dict(id1=s1))`

Comment: Thank you all for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple ways you can format your string, but this is how I would do it using an f string;

```
val = "O'brien"
s1 = f"{{\"id1\":\"{val}\"}}"
```

s1 is then equal to

```
{"id1":"O'Brien"}
```

If you want to use `.format(x)` it needs to be outside the outermost quote and you need to escape the outermost curly brackets

```
s1 = "{{\"id1\":\"{}\"}}".format(val)
```